# Why isn't my dynamic price working till the quantity is over 2?

Tags: jquery

I'm building a dynamic price into a magento product page and I'm having an issue with some quantity up / down buttons when the quantity increases or decrease the price will change to reflect the new price.

Ive got the calculations working to change the base price when the quantity goes over 3, 5 or 10 so thats not an issue its the fact its reflecting the price when it has a quantity of 2 but its on 1.

Any ideas would be awesome.

[image]

```
//QUANTITY BUTTONS

var upBtn = jQuery('#btn-qty-up');
var downBtn = jQuery('#btn-qty-down');
var currentQty = document.getElementById('qty_extention'); 
var qty = currentQty.value; 
if(qty < 2){

}
downBtn.click(function(){
    var currentQty = document.getElementById('qty_extention'); 
    var qty = currentQty.value; 
    //console.log(qty);
    //console.log('down');
    if(!isNaN( qty ) && qty > 0 ){
        currentQty.value--;


        //VARIBLES DECLARED

        var newPrice = jQuery('#dynamic_pricing').find('h1');
        var screwinput = jQuery('select#attribute186').find(":selected").text();

        var calPrice;
        var QtyPrice;

        //IF QUANTITY IS EMPTY OR NULL GIVE WARNING AND STOP
        /*if(qty.length === 0 || qty === ''){
            //warnings.show().html('Quantity Missing').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
            stop();
        } */

        //IF QUANTITY IS MORE THAN X THEN PRICE IS X
        switch(true) {
            case (qty <= 2):
                QtyPrice = '12.95';
                break;
            case (qty >=3 && qty <= 4):
                QtyPrice = '12.30';
                break;
            case (qty >=5 && qty <= 9):
                QtyPrice = '11.65';
                break;
            case (qty >=10):
                QtyPrice = '10.95';
                break;
        }

        //if(screwinput == 'No') {
            calPrice = (QtyPrice * qty);
        //} else {
        //   calPrice = ((1.95 * quantity) + (QtyPrice * quantity));
        //}

        newPrice.html('£' + calPrice.toFixed(2));

    }         




    return false;
});

upBtn.click(function(){
    var currentQty = document.getElementById('qty_extention'); 
    var qty = currentQty.value; 
    //console.log(qty);
    //console.log('up');
    if( !isNaN( qty )) {
        currentQty.value++;

        //VARIBLES DECLARED

        var newPrice = jQuery('#dynamic_pricing').find('h1');
        var screwinput = jQuery('select#attribute186').find(":selected").text();

        var calPrice;
        var QtyPrice;

        //IF QUANTITY IS EMPTY OR NULL GIVE WARNING AND STOP
        /*
        if(qty.length === 0 || qty === ''){
            //warnings.show().html('Quantity Missing').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
            stop();
        } */

        //IF QUANTITY IS MORE THAN X THEN PRICE IS X
        switch(true) {
            case (qty <= 2):
                QtyPrice = '12.95';
                break;
            case (qty >=3 && qty <= 4):
                QtyPrice = '12.30';
                break;
            case (qty >=5 && qty <= 9):
                QtyPrice = '11.65';
                break;
            case (qty >=10):
                QtyPrice = '10.95';
                break;
        }

        //if(screwinput == 'No') {
            calPrice = (QtyPrice * qty);
        //} else {
        //   calPrice = ((1.95 * quantity) + (QtyPrice * quantity));
        //}

        newPrice.html('£' + calPrice.toFixed(2));
    }




    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `calPrice = (QtyPrice * qty);` to `calPrice = (QtyPrice * currentQty.value);` the same with the other one